# Calling C DLL from C++ gives Access Violation but C# project with DllImport working

Tags: c++, c, dll

I have a 32-bit 3rd party C DLL that I need to integrate with, but am hitting an error that's difficult to understand/track down.

I can compile and successfully link a simple C++ 32-bit app consisting of the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" int __stdcall external_method(int cardno);

int main()
{
    int n = external_method(0);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run the app though in debug mode it gives the following:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x100AADF5 (ExternalModule.dll) in 
ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

However, if I create a simple C# application that uses DllImport/PInvoke to call the same function it runs fine:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("ExternalModule.dll")]
        public static extern int external_method(int n);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            external_method(0);
            Debug.WriteLine("YES!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to understand how one can work and the other fail. Unfortunately I have no access to the developer of the C DLL.

Any help much appreciated.

*Update* Thanks for the comments. Here is the header file entry for the method:

```
int __stdcall exernal_method(int cardno);
```

Am reasonably sure that the calling convention is ok. The DLL is being loaded because using the debug version of the DLL I can see it output some messages to the debug output before it fails.

Could it be an issue with stack being corrupted on exit of the method? I tried a couple of different calling conventions but this is the only one that the linker was able to work with.

Comment: Not a C# user, but could it be, that there is a calling convention mismatch?

Comment: There is no difference between your C# and your C code.  You'll have to look for an environmental cause.  And a phone number.

Comment: Could it be that your C++ program can not find the DLL or finds a different version of it? The linker probably just links to an import lib, so it won't complain.

Comment: Debugger or it didn't happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack corruption is unlikely.

One possible reason is different DLL loading method. Your C++ app loads it statically (Windows loads your DLL before the process launched), C# dynamically (CLR loads the DLL after the process started to run). To test this hypothesis, remove ExternalModule.lib from linker, change your C++ code to call LoadLibrary  and GetProcAddress instead.

Another possible reason is C# runtime initializes COM, C++ app doesn’t, and your DLL tried to use COM. In your C++ app, try to add CoInitialize[Ex] before your exernal_method.

Comment: It was the second reason! Thank you

Comment: @jugglingcats You’re welcome. Also don’t forget to CoUninitialize. Usually it should be done just before a thread quits.